# Backpropagation Algorithm Implementation

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj658979.aspx). I'm using the article to understand the logic, but I've implemented it differently using `structs`.

## The problem

The problem is that it never converges to the desired outputs. I don't get the output that I want. Which means that the weights are not updated correctly. If I train the network for a sufficiently large number of times, the output stop changing, which means the weights don't get updated so the network thinks that it has got the correct weights, but the output shows otherwise.

Each neuron holds an array of `Paths`. Weight is a property of `Path` and the `Neurons` can send values 'down a' `Path` and it gets to the `Neuron` on the other side.

Below is the code...

```
const double e =2.7182818284;
```

Neuron:

```
struct Neuron{

double value;   //Local input
double bias;
double gradient;
double out; //Output value
Path *p;    //path array 
int nc; //number of paths/connections belonging to *this



};
```

Path:

```
struct Path{
    double weight;
    double prevDelta;
    double delta;
    int nid;    //neuron id in *n
};
```

`Layers` contain `Neurons`. `Paths` identify `Neurons` with an integer `nid`, which is the index of the `Neuron` array in the neighboring `Layer`.

Layer:

```
struct Layer{

    int nneurons;   //number of neurons in cluster/layer
    Neuron *n;   //Local Neuron array to reference
    Layer *neighbor;


    void Transfer(int nid)  //compute target Neuron's input and assign it to it

    {

        double valueOut=0;
        Neuron *temp;
        temp=&n[nid];

        //for each connection, send w*v to paired neuron
        for(int i=0; i<n[nid].nc; i++)
        {
            valueOut=temp->p[i].weight * temp->out;

            //neuron nid(as referenced by p[]), which is in the other layer, receives the value
            neighbor->n[temp->p[i].nid].value+=valueOut;

        }


    }

    void Initialize(int size)
    {

            nneurons=size;
            n=new Neuron[nneurons];

            for(int i=0; i<nneurons; i++)
            {
                n[i].value=0.0;
                n[i].bias=1.0;
                n[i].out=0.0;

            }

    }

    void FormConnections(Layer& nl)//with neighboring layer
    {
        neighbor=&nl;

        int nCon=neighbor->nneurons;

        for(int i=0; i<nneurons; i++)
        {

            n[i].nc=nCon;
            n[i].p=new Path[nCon];

            //neuron 'i' will link its paths to neurons in the other layer
            for(int ii=0; ii<n[i].nc; ii++)
            {
                n[i].p[ii].weight=1.0;
                n[i].p[ii].prevDelta=0.0;
                n[i].p[ii].nid=ii;

            }

        }

    }

};
```

Brain(the Neural Network):

```
 class Brain{
   public:

double eta;
double alpha;
Layer   input,
        hidden,
        output;

double *target;

void GetInput(double* in){
    for(int i=0; i<input.nneurons; i++)
        input.n[i].value=in[i];

}

void GetDesiredOutput(double* t)
{
    target=t;
}

void Initialize(int inputsize, int hiddensize, int outputsize)
{
    input.Initialize(inputsize);
    hidden.Initialize(hiddensize);
    output.Initialize(outputsize);

    input.FormConnections(hidden);
    hidden.FormConnections(output);

}

void BP()
{

    //Calculate gradients for output
    for(int i=0; i<output.nneurons; i++)
    {output.n[i].gradient=(target[i] - output.n[i].out) * (1 - output.n[i].out) * (1 + output.n[i].out);}

    Neuron* temp;
    for(int i=0; i<hidden.nneurons; i++)
        {
            temp=&hidden.n[i];
            temp->gradient=0;
            //for each connection...
            for(int ii=0; ii<hidden.n[i].nc; ii++)
            {
                //temp's gradient gets values in the form w1*g2 + w2*g2 + ... + wn*gn,
                //where w is the weight of p that leads to output.n[i] from temp(hidden), and g
                //is the gradient of that output at p[CurrentConnection].nid

                temp->gradient+= temp->p[ii].weight * output.n[temp->p[ii].nid].gradient;
            }

            //Multiply the resultant sums with d/dx S(x)
            temp->gradient*= (temp->out)*(1-temp->out);


        }
    /

/---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Calculate delta

        for(int i=0; i<input.nneurons; i++)
        {
            temp=&input.n[i];

            //temp->bias=eta*temp->gradient;

            for(int ii=0; ii<input.n[i].nc; ii++)
            {   
                temp->p[ii].delta=eta* hidden.n[temp->p[ii].nid].gradient* temp->value;
                temp->p[ii].weight=temp->p[ii].prevDelta*alpha+temp->p[ii].delta;
                temp->p[ii].prevDelta=temp->p[ii].delta;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<hidden.nneurons; i++)
        {
            temp=&hidden.n[i];

            temp->bias=eta*temp->gradient;

            for(int ii=0; ii<hidden.n[i].nc; ii++)
            {   temp->p[ii].delta=eta* output.n[temp->p[ii].nid].gradient* temp->value;
                temp->p[ii].weight=temp->p[ii].prevDelta*alpha+temp->p[ii].delta;
                temp->p[ii].prevDelta=temp->p[ii].delta;
            }

        }

        for(int i=0; i<output.nneurons; i++)
        {
            temp=&output.n[i];

            temp->bias=eta*temp->gradient;
        }
    Zero(hidden);
    Zero(output);
    }

    void Process()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<input.nneurons; i++)
        {   input.n[i].out=input.n[i].value;
            input.Transfer(i);//transfer each neuron data in input to hidden
        }
        for(int i=0; i<hidden.nneurons; i++)
        {

            hidden.n[i].out=Sigmoid(hidden.n[i].value + hidden.n[i].bias);

            hidden.Transfer(i);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<output.nneurons; i++)
        {

            output.n[i].out=HyperTan(output.n[i].value + output.n[i].bias);
            cout<<"Output "<<i<<": "<<output.n[i].out<<endl;
        }


    }

    void Zero(Layer &l){ for(int i=0; i<l.nneurons; i++) l.n[i].value=0.0;}
    void Randomize(Layer &l)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<l.nneurons; i++)
        {
            for(int ii=0; ii<l.n[i].nc; ii++)
            {
                l.n[i].p[ii].weight=rand()%100/10;

            }
        }
    }
    Brain(){eta=0.9; alpha=0.4;}

     double Sigmoid(double x)
  {
    if (x < -45.0) return 0.0;
    else if (x > 45.0) return 1.0;
    else return (1.0 / (1.0 + pow(e, -x)));
  }
  double HyperTan(double x)
  {
    if (x < -10.0) return -1.0;
    else if (x > 10.0) return 1.0;
    else return tanh(x);
  }
};
```

A typical program would be:

```
Brain b;

double data[]={1.0,2.0, 3.0};
double ddata[]={-0.25,0.14};



b.Initialize(3,4,2);

b.GetDesiredOutput(ddata);
b.GetInput(data);


b.Process();
b.BP();
```

Example:
eta= 0.9, alpha= 0.4
 for input 1.0, 2.0, 3.0

I get:

> -0.117471 and 0.0661122

The expected output is:

> -0.25, 0.14

**UPDATE(25/12/2013):**
The problem was in calculating the delta values for hidden-to-output weights, and there was an additional error when updating the weights using these new deltas, which all take place in the same for loop. I simply assigned the new weights, while I was supposed to *add* them to the previous weights.

Comment: What is the expected output, and what is your output?

Comment: I kept playing around with it. But here's an example where eta= 0.9, alpha= 0.4 :-
for input 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 
I get: -0.117471 and 0.0661122

The expected output is: -0.25, 0.14

Comment: Just a suggestion - you need to break this down and test each part to see whether its doing what you expect.  Are the initial wights correct, is the BP algorithm adjusting as you would expect for each input, etc - put some debugging output here.  Perhaps someone here will know enough about BP and C++ and have the time to do this for you and spot the issue - but its more likely that you will find it yourself if you take the time to work it out.

Comment: That is very difficult. There is no way to predict the desired behavior for this network. You can't observe the weights and look if they change as you want, because you don't know how those values are supposed to change. This algorithm is supposed to find the network configuration(the weight values) that work best to output the desired results, and you have no idea what those values are. Maybe I should research this more and look at other sources and see if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Okay now I edited my question, why is it still on hold? Most likely the people who closed my question have no idea about this algorithm or Neural Networks, so if they don't understand it, they think the problem is in my wording. You believe these people?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in calculating the delta values for the weights, and there was an additional error when updating the weights using these new deltas, which all take place in the same for-loop. I simply assigned the new weights, while I was supposed to add them to the previous weights. Correct delta calculation and weight assignment:

```
for(int i=0; i<input.nneurons; i++)
    {
        temp=&input.n[i];



        for(int ii=0; ii<input.n[i].nc; ii++)
        {   
            temp->p[ii].delta=eta* hidden.n[temp->p[ii].nid].gradient* temp->out;
            temp->p[ii].weight+=temp->p[ii].prevDelta*alpha +temp->p[ii].delta;
            temp->p[ii].prevDelta=temp->p[ii].delta;



        }

    }
```

And for hidden to output:

```
for(int i=0; i<hidden.nneurons; i++)
    {
        temp=&hidden.n[i];
        temp->bd=eta*temp->gradient;

        temp->bias+=temp->bd+ alpha*temp->pbd;
        temp->pbd=temp->bd;

        for(int ii=0; ii<hidden.n[i].nc; ii++)
        {   
            temp->p[ii].delta=eta* output.n[temp->p[ii].nid].gradient* temp->out;
            temp->p[ii].weight+=temp->p[ii].prevDelta*alpha+ temp->p[ii].delta;
            temp->p[ii].prevDelta=temp->p[ii].delta;


        }

    }
```